# Excel VBA AutoFilter Percentages

Tags: vba, excel, percentage, autofilter

I want to filter a list of industries by using their growth rate as criteria. 
At the end, I want my sheet just showing industries growing >= 10%.

The data I want to filter is in Tabelle1 Column 10 and is shown as percentage. Furthermore, I have stated my criteria 10% (Which should stay variable) on Tabelle2 Cell B3. However, after exectuing the follwing code it is showing me all industries with a growth rate >= 0%.

Does anyone know why and how I can adjust it to my needs?

---

```
Sub AutoFilter()
Dim Bereich As Range
Dim Variable As Long

Set Bereich = Tabelle1.UsedRange
Variable = Tabelle2.Range("B3").Value

Bereich.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Variable

End Sub
```

---

Thank you :)

Comment: Try `Variable = Tabelle2.Range("B3").Text`

Comment: `Tabelle2.Range("B3").Value` What is actual value of this cell? `0.1`, `10`, `10%`? Are values in 10-th field strings or numbers?

Comment: When I use Variable = Tabelle2.Range("B3").Text it shows "Laufzeitfehler '13'". 

The actual Value of Tablle2.Range("B3") is 10% and the values in 10-th field are also shown as percentages, e.g. 19% etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable needs to be at least float if not double, because e.g. `12%` equals `0.12`.

And .AutoFilter property seems to always expect 'en-US' locale values thus the following code should work:

```
Sub AutoFilter()
    Dim Bereich As Range, Variable As Double

    Set Bereich = Tabelle1.UsedRange
    Variable = Tabelle2.Range("B3").Value

    Bereich.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Replace(Variable, ",", ".")
End Sub
```